# Is there an Atom package for a SSH client on a tab?

Tags: github, text-editor, atom-editor

I am using GitHub´s Atom text editor.

I installed Atom on my Windows 10 computer. I edit code and sync it to a remote Ubuntu Server using Atom´s remote-sync package. This is being done via SSH.

I am developing a Django project and most of the times I need to restart Apache so that the Python code gets compiled in the remote server.

I want to know if there is a package that I can use to access remotely to my linux server via SSH and run bash commands. Preferably one that can be loaded on a tab.

I tried term, term2, term3, terminal but all of them are not working. I get errors on pty.js when trying to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shellinabox/) and use a web view package to access the webpage.

Comment: any web terminal would work.. thanks! Never thought about this.